# How we can catch/get a field from an Extends Form Type after POSTing

Tags: php, symfony

I have (FormType2) as Extends Form Type from FormType1. the new fields of FormType2 appear, also those of FormType1, means that my Extends Type work correctly ... but when I post the form. the fields of FormType2 could not be retrieved ... I got this error message :

Neither the property "nychaCode" nor one of the methods "getNychaCode()", "isNychaCode()", "hasNychaCode()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "Bundle\Model\DiscountCode".

How I can resolve this issue ? Thanks.

My AbstractTypeExtension

```php
namespace MyBundle\Form\Type;

use MyBundle\Model\DiscountCodeNYCHA;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class DiscountCodeNYCHAType extends AbstractTypeExtension{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add(DiscountCodeNYCHA::ATTRIBUTE_NYCHA_CODE, null, array('label' => 'NYCHA Tenant Account Number', 'attr' => array('autocomplete' => 'off'));
        $builder->add(DiscountCodeNYCHA::ATTRIBUTE_BIRTH_YEAR, null, array('label' => 'Birth Year', 'attr' => array('autocomplete' => 'off'));
        $builder->add(DiscountCodeNYCHA::ATTRIBUTE_BIRTH_DAY, null, array('label' => 'Birth Day', 'attr' => array('autocomplete' => 'off'));
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return 'edDiscountCode';
    }
}
```

Model DiscountCodeNYCHA

```php
namespace MyBundle\Model;


use Bundle\Model\DiscountCode;

class DiscountCodeNYCHA extends DiscountCode {

    const ATTRIBUTE_NYCHA_CODE = 'nychaCode';
    const ATTRIBUTE_BIRTH_YEAR = 'birthYear';
    const ATTRIBUTE_BIRTH_DAY = 'birthDay';

    private $nychaCode;
    private $birthYear;
    private $birthDay;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getNychaCode()
    {
        return $this->nychaCode;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $nychaCode
     */
    public function setNychaCode($nychaCode)
    {
        $this->nychaCode = $nychaCode;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBirthDay()
    {
        return $this->birthDay;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $birthDay
     */
    public function setBirthDay($birthDay)
    {
        $this->birthDay = $birthDay;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBirthYear()
    {
        return $this->birthYear;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $birthYear
     */
    public function setBirthYear($birthYear)
    {
        $this->birthYear = $birthYear;
    }

    public function isEmpty(){
        if(is_null($this->nychaCode) && is_null($this->birthYear) && is_null($this->birthDay)){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

My FormType

```php
use Bundle\Model\DiscountCode;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class DiscountCodeType extends AbstractType {

    function __construct() {
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add(DiscountCode::ATTRIBUTE_FIRST_TWO_LETTERS_FIRST_NAME, null, array('label'=>'First two letters of first name','attr' => array('autocomplete' => 'off')));
        $builder->add(DiscountCode::ATTRIBUTE_FIRST_TWO_LETTERS_LAST_NAME, null, array('label'=>'First two letters of last name','attr' => array('autocomplete' => 'off')));
        $builder->add(DiscountCode::ATTRIBUTE_LAST_FOUR_DIGITS_SSN, null, array('label'=>'Last four digits of Social Security Number','attr' => array('autocomplete' => 'off')));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        parent::setDefaultOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => get_class(new DiscountCode()),
            'translation_domain' => 'DiscountCodeType',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of this type.
     *
     * @return string The name of this type
     */
    public function getName() {
        return 'edDiscountCode';
    }
}
```

Model DiscountCode :

```php
namespace Bundle\Model;

class DiscountCode {
    const ATTRIBUTE_FIRST_TWO_LETTERS_FIRST_NAME = 'firstTwoLettersFirstName'; // First two letters of first name
    const ATTRIBUTE_FIRST_TWO_LETTERS_LAST_NAME = 'firstTwoLettersLastName'; // First two letters of last name
    const ATTRIBUTE_LAST_FOUR_DIGITS_SSN = 'lastFourDigitsSsn'; // Last four digits of Social Security Number

    private $firstTwoLettersFirstName;
    private $firstTwoLettersLastName;
    private $lastFourDigitsSsn;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFirstTwoLettersFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstTwoLettersFirstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $firstTwoLettersFirstName
     */
    public function setFirstTwoLettersFirstName($firstTwoLettersFirstName)
    {
        $this->firstTwoLettersFirstName = $firstTwoLettersFirstName;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFirstTwoLettersLastName()
    {
        return $this->firstTwoLettersLastName;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $firstTwoLettersLastName
     */
    public function setFirstTwoLettersLastName($firstTwoLettersLastName)
    {
        $this->firstTwoLettersLastName = $firstTwoLettersLastName;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLastFourDigitsSsn()
    {
        return $this->lastFourDigitsSsn;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $lastFourDigitsSsn
     */
    public function setLastFourDigitsSsn($lastFourDigitsSsn)
    {
        $this->lastFourDigitsSsn = $lastFourDigitsSsn;
    }

    public function isEmpty(){
        if(is_null($this->firstTwoLettersFirstName) && is_null($this->firstTwoLettersLastName) && is_null($this->lastFourDigitsSsn)){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE : I just update the setters and getters of DiscountCodeNYCHA to public access, were protected.

Comment: aint the problem that at your "Model DiscountCodeNYCHA" the getter and setter are protected instaed of public ?

Comment: Same error, even if my setters and getters en DiscountCodeNYCHA are public access :(

Comment: @KamDane Are you using Symfony framework, or only its components (as standalone)?

Comment: @xurshid29 I'm using Symfony framework fully ...

Comment: @KamDane I think you should remove `data_class` if you're not using Doctrine, and manually manage the data, you can read [about this here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.5/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class).

Comment: @xurshid29 Thanks ... It works :) ... I got the value :), see my var_dump() :  
  
`["discountCode":"MyBundle\Model\SubscriptionPurchase":private]=>
    array(6) {  
      ["firstTwoLettersFirstName"]=>  
      NULL  
      ["firstTwoLettersLastName"]=>  
      NULL  
      ["lastFourDigitsSsn"]=>  
      NULL  
      ["nychaCode"]=>  
      string(11) "123NYCHA456"  
      ["birthYear"]=>  
      string(4) "1978"  
      ["birthDay"]=>  
      string(2) "07"  
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you aren't telling your extended form type to use your extended model class.  Since you don't override **setDefaultOptions**, it uses your definition from DiscountCodeType, where **data_class** is set to DiscountType.

Add this to **DiscountCodeNYCHAType:**

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {

    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => get_class(new DiscountCodeNYCHA()),
        'translation_domain' => 'DiscountCodeType',
    ]);
}
```

Also, in **DiscountCodeType**, you don't have to call

```
parent::setDefaultOptions($resolver);
```

because you are extending *Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType*, in which every function has an empty definition.

Comment: Thanks Jason !! ... That's true, now I got my my field as an object of DiscountCodeNYCHA, cause before, was just a array.

Comment: No problem. That's the reason why I suggest keeping `data_class` even if you're not persisting to a database, because otherwise Symfony just returns array data and you can't treat it like your DiscountCode/DiscountCodeNYCHA classes. Then you can add Assertions/use functions/constants in that class/etc.